# sumByDouble required Double found Double?

Tags: kotlin, option-type

I have the following code:

```
materialList.sumByDouble { elem -> elem.let { it.getPrice()?.toDouble() * it.getQuantity()?.toDouble() }}
```

> Type mismatch. Required: Double, Found: Double?

Why do I have this kind of error? I've already removed the optional with the elem.let statement, no?

Comment: *no?* - no, use `elem?.let` for that

Comment: `getPrice()` and `getQuantity()` are returning nullables. In this case, let is not really needed.

Comment: Unless you're declared your list as `List<Element?>`, then I don't think elem was ever nullable in the first place. I think it's more likely your list is `List<Element>`. You probably want to post your `Element` class; that's the source of your trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following :

```
materialList.sumByDouble { elem -> elem.let { it.getPrice()?.toDouble() ?: 0.0 * it.getQuantity()?.toDouble() ?: 0.0 }
```

What the code above does, is assign a default value of 0.0 if either of those are evaluated to be null (Well, it assigns 0.0 to the value evaluated to be null, to be exact)

The reason for this is because your `it.getPrice()?` could be null, as well as your `it.getQuantity()?`, so what this does is essentially the same as this (entirely pseudocode)

```
if(it.getQuantity() == null){
 use 0.0 to perform this calculation
} else {
 use it.getQuantity()
 }
```

What `Type mismatch. Required: Double, Found: Double?` this is saying, is that the method expects a non-null double value and you are providing potentially null values

---

on a side-note:

> I've already removed the optional with the elem.let statement, no?

doing this:

```
{ elem -> elem.let { stillPotentiallyNull ->
```

is simply a way to insure that you get an instance of `elem` which can not be changed by threads, however, if you did this:

```
{ elem -> elem?.let { definitelyNotNull ->
```

Then you get an instance of `elem` which is both safe from threads and can not be null, but this does not mean that the objects inside `elem` are also not null

---

as pointed out by @AjahnCharles, this answer is simply to explain why you're having this problem and potentially how to solve it using default values, however, you should consider how to filter out your list into non-null objects as another solution as well.

One potential solution, although it is dangerous, is to use the following :

```
it.getPrice()!!.toDouble() * it.getQuantity()!!.toDouble()
```

This is saying that you are 100% sure that these values are not null, and if they are null, this will throw a null-pointer exception.

Extra documentation you might find useful : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: OP should start by questioning what it means to have null price or null quantity (under what conditions does this occur?). Do you really want to ignore the cost of an item if the price or quantity is missing? It _might_ be more correct to make the fields non-nullable, or to reject the data as invalid.

Comment: i agree @AjahnCharles. for `getQuantity` it is potentially fine to be using 0.0, for price however that's business logic OP has to implement :) given the information and the code at hand, i figured this was enough of an answer to help them understand

Comment: to start filtering out null values is an entirely different question, at least in my opinion @AjahnCharles

Comment: check the last edit @AjahnCharles, i added the double-bang option as well, although i personally hate this approach

Answer (score 0):

if you are confident that it.getPrice() and it.getQuantity() will not return null value then you can use below code for the same:-**not null operator(!!)**
materialList.sumByDouble { elem -> elem.let { it.getPrice()**!!**.toDouble() * it.getQuantity()**!!**.toDouble() }}

Comment: If you're confident that they _never_ return null, you can go further by removing the `?` in their declarations in elem's class.

Comment: but if he just removed? and do not use !! then the compiler will throw the error as not null is required.

Comment: If you declare the fields/methods (in their class, ex: `Element`) as not nullable (no "?") then you don't need any `!!` in this code.